# Ubuntu 18.04.1 Doesn't suspend properly

Tags: suspend, power-management

When my laptop goes to sleep, the screen is shut off, but the OS is apparently stuck in the middle of the process. When I wake it up, I see the "Computer will suspend soon" message, but it's not fully awake - The display flickers when I do anything, when I click on stuff it responds very slowly if at all, the only thing that works is this incongruous pause button.

[image]

If I click the button, the computer finishes going to sleep, which allows me to wake it up to the lock screen.

I wanted to report a bug, but running `ubuntu-bug` doesn't let me add an explanation so I figured it will be incoherent.

---

```
Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
GNOME 3.28.2
64-bit
Lenovo G50-70
```